# Eclipse CDT: Class already exists (but doesn't)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When I try to create a new Class using the CDT Eclipse "New C++ Class" Wizard, I get the error message "Class already exists".

Fact is: a class with similar name existed in my project but the source files are definitely deleted. I now want to re-implement that class.

My question is: Is there any way I can force Eclipse to update its "class cache" or whatever it is that keeps Eclipse from forgetting about this zombie class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual solution is to re-index the project, as mentioned in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/59925/).

> Select project, right-click > Index > Rebuild Index

This is also what is specified in [bug 165636](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=165636).

Comment: Thanks. I thought clicking on "Refresh" would be enough.